# store security and user data in sessionstorage or localstorage

Tags: local-storage, frontend, session-storage, web-storage

I am working on an angular-springboot application and for login/security consideration I am wondering if I must store the user and security data in sessionstorage or localstorage

for sessionStorage the data is persisted only until the window or tab is closed, while with localStorage the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data

I am tempted to say that sessionStorage is the right choice, but in most of discussions on internet they talk about using localStorage. What is the reason ? With localStorage, if you don't clear the data while login out, the next time you open the browser or you turn on your computer, the data will be still stored in the localStorage ! So, for that choice, you have two conditions 1) Logout, 2) Clear the data. is that right ?

Comment: I think, you are right. So what's the problem?

Comment: I think you see most people talk about localStorage is because sessionStorage is 100% the same API, it just expires differently.